# Typing to mark return values of current class type or any of its subclasses

Tags: python, oop, subclass, mypy, python-typing

I want to make sure that the `from_dict` in the following method works well in its subclasses as well. Currently, its typing does not work (mypy error "Incompatible return value type"). I think because the subclass is returning an instance of the subclass and not an instance of the super class.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from abc import ABC
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar, Type


@dataclass
class Statement(ABC):
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls) -> Statement:
        return cls()


@dataclass
class Parent(ABC):
    SIGNATURE_CLS: ClassVar[Type[Statement]]

    def say(self) -> Statement:
        # Initialize a Statement through a from_dict classmethod
        return self.SIGNATURE_CLS.from_dict()


@dataclass
class ChildStatement(Statement):
    pass


@dataclass
class Child(Parent, ABC):
    SIGNATURE_CLS = ChildStatement

    def say(self) -> ChildStatement:
        # Initialize a ChildStatement through a from_dict classmethod
        # that ChildStatement inherits from Statement
        return self.SIGNATURE_CLS.from_dict()
```

The code above yields this MyPy error:

```
Incompatible return value type (got "Statement", expected "ChildStatement")  [return-value]
```

I think this is a use case for `TypeVar` in `Statement` but I am not sure how to implement and - especially - what the meaning behind it is.

Comment: This looks like it would be solved using the [new `Self` type hint](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) (available from python 3.11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass instance **is** an instance of its super class, according to typing rules. The error you are seeing is because `from_dict` is typed to be returning a `Statement`, and you are trying to return that value from `say`, which is guaranteed to return `ChildStatement`. So your problem is that you could potentially return more generic `Statement` where more specific `ChildStatement` is expected.

You need to somehow ensure MyPy that:

1. `from_dict` returns its actual class, not generic `Statement`.
2. `SIGNATURE_CLS` of `Child` will be `ChildStatement` and not possibly `Statement` (just assigning `ChildStatement` is not enough as you explicitly typed it as `ClassVar[Type[Statement]]`

You can do that with following pieces of code:

1. use typing.Self to reflect `return cls()`

```
from typing import Self

@dataclass
class Statement(ABC):
    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls) -> Self:
        return cls()
```

(It's important to note that `typing.Self` is a very fresh addition introduced in Python 3.11, you might also need to update your MyPy to be able to take this into account)

2. Explicitly type `Child.SIGNATURE_CLS`

```
@dataclass
class Child(Parent, ABC):
    SIGNATURE_CLS : ClassVar[Type[ChildStatement]] = ChildStatement
```

As a final note, I wonder about the sensibility of `Statement.from_dict()` method, as it isn't any different than just using the standard constructor of `Statement()`.

Comment: I read the PEP, and the use-case they describe with `Self` for using it in class methods is indeed exactly what I need!

Comment: With a "plain old" TypeVar it'd be `_T = TypeVar('_T', bound='Statement'); class Statement(ABC): @classmethod def from_dict(cls: type[_T]) -> _T: return cls()`